# How to build my adventure world

Tags: science-fiction, worldbuilding-process

I am creating a world that a call "adventure world". The concept is loose because I am basing it on a game engine that I make for Android in Java. The way I create my world is like the following.

```
package dev.game.adventure;

import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Subclass to World that builds up the Adventure World.
 */

public class AdventureWorld extends World {
    // testar commit 2017-12-28 holger

    public String messsage = "HELLO WORLD";

    public AdventureWorld(Adventure a, TextView t, AdventureActivity target, PlaceView ag) {
        super(a);
        setAg(ag);
        // Create all places
        createPlace("Heaven", target, R.mipmap.dungeon2);
        createPlace("Dungeon3", target, R.mipmap.dungeon3);
        createPlace("Dungeon2", target, R.mipmap.dungeon2);
        createPlace("Dungeon", target, R.mipmap.dungeon5);
        createPlace("Dungeon4", target, R.mipmap.dungeon3);

        createPlace("Town", target, R.mipmap.town);
        createPlace("Darkshire", target, R.mipmap.darkshire);

        //createPlace("Dungeon1", target, R.mipmap.dungeon1);
        createPlace("Kulverten", target, R.mipmap.dungeon4);
        createPlace("Dungeon5", target, R.mipmap.dungeon);
        createPlace("Dungeon6", target, R.mipmap.dugeon6);
        createPlace("Dungeon7", target, R.mipmap.dungeon7);
        createPlace("Dungeon8", target, R.mipmap.dungeon8);
        createPlace("Dungeon9", target, R.mipmap.dungeon9);
        createPlace("Dungeon10", target, R.mipmap.dungeon10);
        createPlace("Dungeon11", target, R.mipmap.dungeon11);
        createPlace("Dungeon12", target, R.mipmap.dungeon12);
        createPlace("Dungeon13", target, R.mipmap.dungeon13);
        createPlace("Dungeon14", target, R.mipmap.dungeon14);
        // createPlace("Dungeon15", target, R.mipmap.dungeon15);
        createPlace("Dungeon16", target, R.mipmap.dungeon16);
        createPlace("Dungeon17", target, R.mipmap.dungeon17);
        createPlace("Dungeon18", target, R.mipmap.dungeon17);
        createPlace("Dungeon19", target, R.mipmap.dungeon19);
        createPlace("Dungeon20", target, R.mipmap.dungeon20);

        createPlace("Elfhome", target, R.mipmap.elfhome);
        createPlace("Evilforest", target, R.mipmap.evilforest);
        createPlace("Graveyard", target, R.mipmap.graveyard);

        createPlace("Dungeon21", target, R.mipmap.dungeon21);
        createPlace("Cemetary", target, R.mipmap.cemetery);

        // Create all connections between places
        connect("Dungeon", "Dungeon5", "Down", "Up");
        connect("Dungeon5", "Kulverten", "Down", "Up");
//        connect("Dungeon", "Dungeon1", "West", "East");
        connect("Dungeon", "Dungeon2", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon", "Dungeon3", "North", "South");
        connect("Dungeon3", "Dungeon8", "North", "South");
        connect("Dungeon", "Town", "South", "North");
        connect("Dungeon5", "Dungeon6", "West", "East");
        connect("Dungeon6", "Dungeon7", "West", "East");
        connect("Town", "Dungeon7", "Down", "Up");
//        connect("Dungeon1", "Town", "North", "South");
        connect("Dungeon8", "Town", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon9", "Town", "West", "East");
        connect("Dungeon9", "Dungeon3", "Down", "Up");
        connect("Dungeon9", "Dungeon10", "Down", "Up");
        connect("Dungeon10", "Dungeon3", "Down", "Up");
        connect("Dungeon11", "Dungeon10", "Down", "Up");
        connect("Dungeon11", "Dungeon3", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon12", "Dungeon11", "Down", "Up");
        connect("Dungeon12", "Dungeon8", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon13", "Dungeon12", "Down", "Up");
        connect("Dungeon13", "Dungeon4", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon4", "Dungeon14", "Up", "Down");
        connect("Dungeon14", "Dungeon13", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon14", "Dungeon8", "North", "South");
        //    connect("Dungeon15", "Dungeon14", "East", "West");
        //  connect("Dungeon15", "Dungeon8", "South", "North");
        connect("Dungeon16", "Dungeon14", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon16", "Dungeon7", "South", "North");
        connect("Dungeon12", "Dungeon16", "Up", "Down");
        connect("Dungeon17", "Dungeon7", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon18", "Dungeon16", "South", "North");
        connect("Dungeon18", "Dungeon19", "Up", "Down");
        connect("Elfhome", "Dungeon17", "Down", "Up");
//        connect("Elfhome", "Dungeon1", "Up", "Down");
        connect("Dungeon19", "Elfhome", "East", "West");
//        connect("Dungeon19", "Dungeon15", "North", "South");
        connect("Dungeon20", "Dungeon19", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon20", "Graveyard", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon21", "Dungeon19", "East", "West");
        connect("Dungeon21", "Graveyard", "Up", "Down");
        connect("Cemetary", "Dungeon19", "Up", "Down");
        connect("Cemetary", "Graveyard", "East", "West");

        connect("Evilforest", "Elfhome", "Up", "Down");
        connect("Dungeon14", "Evilforest", "South", "North");
        connect("Graveyard", "Evilforest", "South", "North");
        connect("Graveyard", "Dungeon19", "Down", "Up");
        connect("Graveyard", "Darkshire", "North", "South");
        connect("Dungeon21", "Darkshire", "North", "South");


        getPlace("Town").addThing(new CocaCola("Lukewarm Coca-Cola"));
        getPlace("Town").addThing(new CocaCola("Daft Coca-Cola"));
        getPlace("Town").addThing(new CocaCola("Cold Coca-Cola"));
        getPlace("Town").addThing(new CocaCola("Coca-Cola Light"));
        getPlace("Town").addThing(new CocaCola("Cuba Cola"));

        getPlace("Dungeon2").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));
        getPlace("Dungeon3").addThing(new Key("Key"));

        getPlace("Dungeon3").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));
        getPlace("Dungeon4").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));
        getPlace("Dungeon5").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));
        getPlace("Dungeon6").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));
        getPlace("Dungeon7").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));
        getPlace("Dungeon8").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));
        getPlace("Dungeon9").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));
        getPlace("Dungeon10").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));
        getPlace("Dungeon11").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));
        getPlace("Dungeon12").addThing(new Scroll("Scroll"));


        getPlace("Darkshire").addThing(new CocaCola("Lukewarm Coca-Cola"));
        getPlace("Darkshire").addThing(new CocaCola("Daft Coca-Cola"));
        getPlace("Darkshire").addThing(new CocaCola("Cold Coca-Cola"));
        getPlace("Darkshire").addThing(new CocaCola("Coca-Cola Light"));
        getPlace("Darkshire").addThing(new CocaCola("Cuba Cola"));


        Simulation sim = new Simulation(target);

        // Load images to be used as appearance-parameter for persons
        int robotAppearance = R.mipmap.robot;
        int pirateAppearance = R.mipmap.pirate;
        int skeletonAppearance = R.mipmap.skeletor;
        int zombieAppearance = R.mipmap.brainzombie;
        int goblinAppearance = R.mipmap.goblin;
        // int monsterAppearance = R.mipmap.monster;
        int soldierAppearance = R.mipmap.soldier;
        int heroAppearance = R.mipmap.hero;
        int guardAppearance = R.mipmap.guard;
        int vikingAppearance = R.mipmap.viking;
        int foxAppearance = R.mipmap.fox;
        int ghostAppearance = R.mipmap.ghost;
        int ogreAppearance = R.mipmap.ogre;
        int rockmonsterAppearance = R.mipmap.rockmonster;
        int knightAppearance = R.mipmap.knight;
        int lobGoblinAppearance = R.mipmap.goblinking;
        int raptorAppearance = R.mipmap.raptor;
        int armyjoeAppearance = R.mipmap.armyjoe;
        int arabAppearance = R.mipmap.arab;
        int karenAppearance = R.mipmap.karen;
        int gravelAppearance = R.mipmap.gravel;
        int guard2Appearance = R.mipmap.guard2;
        int chibiknight1Appearance = R.mipmap.chibiknight1;
        int executionerAppearance = R.mipmap.executioner;
        int stonemaneAppearance = R.mipmap.stoneman;
        int thorkwarriorAppearance = R.mipmap.thorkwarrior;
        int mikeAppearance = R.mipmap.mike;
        int joanaAppearance = R.mipmap.joana;
        int ninjaAppearance = R.mipmap.ninja;
        int ninjabaronessAppearance = R.mipmap.ninjabaroness;
        int georgeAppearance = R.mipmap.george;
        int jackthugAppearance = R.mipmap.jackthug;
        int executioner2Appearance = R.mipmap.executioner2;
        int alienbossAppearance = R.mipmap.alienboss;
        int brockAppearance = R.mipmap.brock;
        int chibiknightAppearance = R.mipmap.chibiknight;
        int chinesekingAppearance = R.mipmap.chineseking;
        int chibisamuraiAppearance = R.mipmap.chibisamurai;
        int draculaAppearance = R.mipmap.dracula;
        int purpleskinalienAppearance = R.mipmap.purpleskinalien;
        //int zombiefarmerAppearance = R.mipmap.zombiefarmer;
        int androidbossAppearance = R.mipmap.androidboss;
        int warbotAppearance = R.mipmap.warbot;
        int executioner3Appearance = R.mipmap.executioner3;
        int redbotAppearance = R.mipmap.redbot;


        // --- Add new persons here ---
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Stoneman", stonemaneAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Thorkwarrior", thorkwarriorAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "ChibiKnight01", chibiknight1Appearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Executioner", executionerAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Karen", karenAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Gravel", gravelAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "DungeonGuard", guard2Appearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Goblin", goblinAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Skeleton", skeletonAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Robot", robotAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Zombie", zombieAppearance, target);
        //   new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Monster", monsterAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Soldier", soldierAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Hero", heroAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Guard", guardAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Viking", vikingAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Fox", foxAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Ghost", ghostAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Ogre", ogreAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Rockmonster", rockmonsterAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Knight", knightAppearance, target);
        //  new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Iobgoblin", lobGoblinAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Raptor", raptorAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Army Joe", armyjoeAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Arab", arabAppearance, target);

        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Mike", mikeAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "George", georgeAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Alienboss", alienbossAppearance, target);
        // new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Executioner3", executioner3Appearance, target);

        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Brock", brockAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Chibiknight", chibiknightAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Chineseking", chinesekingAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Chibisamurai", chibisamuraiAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Dracula", draculaAppearance, target);

        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Joana", joanaAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "AndroidBoss", androidbossAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "RedBot", redbotAppearance, target);

        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Ninja", ninjaAppearance, target);

        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Ninjabaroness", ninjabaronessAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Jackthug", jackthugAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "Executioner2", executioner2Appearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "PurpleSkinAlien", purpleskinalienAppearance, target);
        //   new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "ZombiFarmer", zombiefarmerAppearance, target);
        if (Math.random() > 0.2)
            new WalkingPerson(sim, this, "WarBot", warbotAppearance, target);
        //
         /*
         /*
        new LabAssistant(sim, this, "Kate", asseAppearance);
        new LabAssistant(sim, this, "Jenna", asseAppearance);
*/
        new Troll(sim, this, "Troll", target);
/*
        new Necromancer(sim, this, "Necromancer", necromancerAppearance);
        new NinjaPersonality(sim, this, "Ninja", null);
*/
    }

    /**
     * The place where persons are placed by default
     *
     * @return The default place.
     */
    public Place defaultPlace() {
        return randomPlace();//
        // return getPlace( "Dungeon" );
    }

    /**
     * A random place where persons are placed by default
     *
     * @return A random place.
     */
    public Place randomPlace() {

        String[] places = {"Heaven", "Dungeon3", "Dungeon2", "Dungeon", "Dungeon4", "Dungeon5", "Dungeon10", "Dungeon11", "Dungeon12", "Dungeon13", "Dungeon14", "Dungeon16", "Dungeon17", "Dungeon18", "Dungeon19", "Dungeon20", "Dungeon21", "Darkshire", "Elfhome", "Evilforest", "Graveyard", "Dungeon6", "Dungeon7", "Dungeon8", "Dungeon9", "Town",
                "Kulverten"};

        return getPlace((String) (places[((int) (Math.random() * places.length))]));
    }

    public void connect(String p1, String p2, String door1, String door2) {
        Place place1 = getPlace(p1);
        Place place2 = getPlace(p2);
        place1.addExit(door1, place2);
        place2.addExit(door2, place1);
    }
}
```

I have not had the time to create a level editor. Now I wonder if there is a more efficient way for me to create the world and make it more logical, and how I can create a story around the world. I have nearly unlimited access to game characters of different types and looks:

[image]

But I don't have the concept or any story to tell. I think it would be reasonable to create a use case so that I can improve the game engine. Right now it is Game Over if you meet the large Troll and it kills you. That is ok for most overall game scenarios, so that there is a way to end the game. Right now you "win" the adventure if you get the key that is originally in Dungeon3 and then you drop the key in the town, then the game goes "Congratulations" and nothing more. It would be more exciting if something cooler happened, for instances freeing a hostage or receiving a reward of some other kind.

I apologize if the question is vague but I am also interested in any improvement I can make to my world.

Comment: Wrong exchange. Although, I don't think your question would be a good fit on the main site either as it's too broad.

Comment: This sort of question belongs on [GameDevelopment.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). That site is for programming games. This is for tips about developing the world your game is set it. Once you have a plot and characters mapped out, you can post questions here as you try to develop your setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Move Data to Data Files

### Map

You could read the map from a flat file. The map could be ascii art, where special characters represent connections ('=' for two way, '-' for one way) and other characters (a-z,A-Z,0-9) map to defined regions.

You could page maps based on 'chapters' of your story.

### Triggers

It didn't look like you have any triggers, but that was only part of the world. You could add triggers and actions to the room, so that when the character enters a room the trigger fires, presenting a message or checking for a special item in inventory.

### Plot, Story

Room definitions, triggers, and custom text can be done in separate flat files.

### Quests

You could also add a list of quests that could be applied to the character (maybe applied from triggers).

Comment: Generally, the high-level'ish the better. You'd want to _execute_ quests and plot data files, so depending on who is writing them, you'd load further Java classes or feed it to an embedded interpreter.

Comment: Its great if you can help the OP, but you should do it at the appropriate site. If a question is clearly off-topic, you shouldn't answer it here.

Comment: It is great help that I should use quests. Currently the quest is the bring a key to the town but I haven't sorted out why. If you bring the key to the town then you have completed the adventure.